# Set reverse_iterator::rbegin() and reverse_iterator::rend() for class MyString

Tags: c++

```
class MyString
{
    private:
        char *m_string;
        int m_size;
        int m_reserved_size;
    public:
        typedef char * reverse_iterator;
        typedef const char * const_reverse_iterator;

    reverse_iterator rbegin();
    {
        return reverse_iterator(end());
    }
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const;

    reverse_iterator rend();
    {
        return reverse_iterator(begin());
    }
    const_reverse_iterator rend() const;

    int main()
    {
        MyString str("this is a test string");
        MyString::reverse_iterator rit;
        for (rit = str.rbegin(); rit != str.rend(); rit++)cout << *rit;   
    }
```

Expected results : "gnirts tset a si siht" but I have an error. Please help me to do right. Should I define `reverse_iterator` and how I do it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. When I try to compile this I will get loads of errors, most of which are probably not related to your question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please update your answer to include the error you are encountering.

Comment: btw a reverse iterator needs to "count backwards", hence simply using `char*` wont work